# QT: Geometry of a sub-sub-sub-sub-widget in relation to the topmost container widget

Tags: qt

I have a window widget that has a "tree" of sub-widgets under it. the widget I'm interested in, let's call it "x", gives me its geometry object in relation to its own parent. There are several "generations" of parents all the way up to my window widget.

my goal: I want to find out the x,y of "x" in relation to my window, which is not its direct parent.

the "geometry()" of "X" gives me this information relative to its immediate parent. Any function exists to change the relative parent and get geometry() based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [mapTo()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#mapTo) function.